# In SQL Server, what is the best way to filter items for an entire day

Tags: sql-server, filtering

In SQL Server, I want to show all items for a particular day. What is the best way to do this: DATEPART, BETWEEN, OR >= + < ? All 3 should work functionally, but are some of them better/worse for performance?

1)

```
SELECT *
FROM BlogPosts
WHERE DATEPART(yyyy,BlogPostDate) = 2011
    AND DATEPART(m,BlogPostDate) = 5
    AND DATEPART(d,BlogPostDate) = 7
```

2)

```
SELECT *
FROM BlogPosts
WHERE BlogPostDate BETWEEN '2011-05-07' AND '2011-05-07 23:59:59'
```

3)

```
  SELECT *
    FROM BlogPosts
    WHERE BlogPostDate >= '2011-05-07' 
        AND BlogPostDate < '2011-05-08'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Out of the options you have presented. Number 3 as it is both sargable and will work.

Number 1 is not sargable (can't use an index).

Number 2 will miss valid datetimes such as `2011-05-07 23:59:59.997` (and the exact maximum datetime that you would have to use here would vary between `smalldatetime`, `datetime`, and `datetime2(x)`)

If you are on SQL Server 2008 an alternative option which **is** sargable despite appearances is

```
 SELECT *     
 FROM BlogPosts     
 WHERE CAST(BlogPostDate AS Date)  = '2011-05-07'
```

However I would still opt for your Number 3 with the `>= .... <` as being more efficient both in terms of the range seeked and also potentially making better use of column statistics. [More details of that here.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34052/3690)

Comment: Can 2) be re-written (i.e. 2011-05-07 23:59:59.999) or is it a lost cause?

Comment: @John - It can be rewritten but in a fragile way and there is no benefit of using 2 over 3. If you try `SELECT CAST('2011-05-07 23:59:59.999' AS datetime)` you will see this gets rounded up to `2011-05-08 00:00:00.000` so you would need to use `'2011-05-07 23:59:59.997` then later if you changed to `datetime2` you would need to go and update all the places you have done this!

Comment: Well, I'm not going to use ... .997. A DBA might understand what I'm doing, but most programmers. And as you said, there is no benefit of doing that over 3) anyway.

Comment: [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer the DateDiff technique below.

```
DECLARE @selectedDate datetime = '2011-05-07'

SELECT * 
  FROM BlogPosts
 WHERE DateDiff(DAY,BlogPostDate, @selectedDate) = 0
```

Comment: I think this is a really clean solution.

Answer (score -1):

Options 1) and 2) will both work.

Option 3 will not work as you expect, since `datetime` has a higher precision than seconds.  So the where clause:

```
WHERE BlogPostDate BETWEEN '2011-05-07' AND '2011-05-07 23:59:59'
```

Would incorrectly filter out:

```
'2011-05-07 23:59:59.500'
```

[Datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)  So this WHERE clause would work:

```
WHERE BlogPostDate BETWEEN '2011-05-07' AND '2011-05-07 23:59:59.997'
```